# Why Firebase needs App Team Id and what is used for?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Firebase Analytics allows my config to also include a App Team ID in my GoogleService-Info.plist.

I haven't provided one when I created my project, and the app seems to work fine.

Why I need a Team ID? and most importantly what its used for?

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000104?hl=en
Add an App Store ID or Team ID

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to supply a TeamID for Dynamic Links and/or Firebase Invites to work. It's needed because Firebase Dynamic Links creates a tiny little website with its own `apple-app-site-association` file that points to your app, and your TeamID is needed for this site to work. You can check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFPo296OQqk) for more information!

Comment: where can i find my app store id ??